# Where are technical papers or documents for Watson Natural Language Understanding like sentiment analysis?

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, sentiment-analysis

I am reading Bluemix Natural Language Understanding [api](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#methods). They are very interesting. What I want to ask is where I can find the technical documents or papers that describe the basic theories or methods behind computations or codes of sentient, emotion, concepts, categories...? How I can know what these apis return measures are based on? There are quite a number of Natural Language Processing (NLP) tools available now. Some tools (e.g. stanford nlp tools -> [paper: Recursive Deep Models for Semantic Compositionality
Over a Sentiment Treebank](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf)) show links to the papers or documents that address what theories and methods their nlp tools are based on or they show THEIR methods of computing sentiment. Will you direct me to the resources that deal with these basic theoretical methods behind computations of Waston NLU sentiment,emotion, concepts, categories...?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @newfind, welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, your question doesn't meet the stackoverflow criteria and is likely to get closed.  See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should try Developerworks to ask your question.

Comment: @Simon, i asked the same at Developerworks, but no answer there.

Comment: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/tocresult.jsp?isnumber=6177717